# Почему может не работать Pjax?

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

Пишу сайт на Yii2. Захотел использовать Pjax. Вызаваю:

```
Pjax::begin(['enablePushState'=>false]);
?>
<a href="/site/add">Добавить</a>
<?php
Pjax::end();
```

По ссылке должна подгружаться форма. Но происходит переход. В js консоли чисто, в debug панеле чисто.

Какие могут быть причины?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно просто не хватает времени на загрузку. Попробуйте

```
Pjax::begin(['enablePushState'=> false, 'timeout' => 10000]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Id может не хватает.

```
<?php
    Pjax::begin([
        'enablePushState' => false,
        'enableReplaceState' => false,
        'id' => 'delivery-content',
        'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']
    ]);
    ?>
<?= Html::a('Оплатить', [Url::to('cart/pay')],
   'id' => 'id',
   'class' => 'btn'
]) ?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

В контроллере должно быть:

```
return $this->renderPartial('_template', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```